# Function template as a parameter to a class template

Tags: c++, templates

<> - read this as a template;

I can do this:

```
void f() {}

//Here I'm declaring a fnc as a <> param
template<void (*fnc)()>
struct Factor { };

int main()
{
  Factor<f> fac;
  return 0;
}
```

but I cannot do this:

```
#include <sstream>

template<class R, class T>
R make_(T first, T second)
{
    std::stringstream interpreter;
    R result = R();
    interpreter << first << '.' << second;
    interpreter >> result;
    return result;
}

//Here I'm (trying) to declare fnc <> as a <> param
template<template<class T,class R> R (*fnc)(T,T)>
struct Factor { };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Factor<make_> fac;
  return 0;
}
```

The BIG Q is: How (if possible) can I declare as a template parameter a fnc template?

**Edit**

Providing that I've used Armen's advise:
I would like to be able to do something like this (in main):

```
Factor<f<"1","02">> m;
```

Then in m I could make a double type out of those args ("1", "02")

Comment: @GMan the BIGGER picture ;) is that I'm trying to create a policy for my Map container (very unusual and very non-standard) that this policy would control by how much "new" capacity would be increased if the allocated mem. would get exhausted. That's why I want this to be able to take 2 params one for real and the second for "unreal" part of the real number and by doing so I would be able to have factor for example 1.5 or 2.5 for increasing capacity for my map.

Comment: @All gotta go (wife wants to watch some movie and I've promised her to do so tonight). Will check all your great comments tommorow. Thanks.

Comment: Steve M's solution will work for you, though JoshD's mention of adding parameters to your make_<> template would work as well, if fnc were altered to accept functions with a return type and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax for that in C++.
What you should do is  instead of function template use functor template, which would fit as a template template parameter.

E.G.

```
template <class R, class T>
struct f
{
    R operator () (T const&)
    {
        //blah
    }
};

template <template<class R, class T> class F >
struct foo
{
    ///...
};

int main()
{
    foo<f> d;
}
```

Comment: @Armen yo my men, would you care to edit your answer with... ahem... appropriate example so my simple, murky brain can be enlightened?

Comment: @Armen I'm still unclear how would I pass arg to f for it's operator()(T const &)?

Comment: @Armen could you plese update your answer and show how can I pass args to f::operator() ?

Comment: @There: I don't quite understand what you mean. In your code I don't see where you pass args. Where do you want to pass args?

Comment: @Armen I want to pass args to f

Comment: @There: You create an instance of F, like F f; and call f(42).

Comment: @Armen you mean create an instance of F inside foo? if that's how it is it won't work for me because I need to specify those args when creating foo.

Comment: @There: I still don't understand what you want to do. Can you provide a (notcompilable) example of what you are trying to do? Including passing args?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax has some issues. What you do at the end with `Factor<make_> fac;` is similar to declaring `vector<map> v;` You need to provide parameters to the template to make it concrete: `Factor<make_<int,int> > fac;`. But that isn't the whole issue; there are many.

What you're doing with your function isn't quite right. You are providing a specific function (f in the first example), which can be done as a constructor parameter. You should reevaluate your design.

Comment: Templates do more than "allow types". Quite a few template metaprogramming techniques depend on the flexibility of templates in this regard.

Comment: @Harper Shelby: yes, I wasn't clear about that. My point was that having a template for a function pointer is misguided. That type of thing can easily be done via a parameter to a constructor. If he were to provide a template parameter that could specify a functor class, that would be more proper (in my opinion).

Comment: While I can see your syntax argument, suppose the OP wants to have `Factor` "remember" that template in order to allow it to call that? Seems like a worthy goal to me.

Comment: @sbi: I'm not sure I follow. Could you elaborate? Are you speaking about `Factor<make_>` specifically?

Comment: @JoshD: Yes. Suppose `Factor` needs to invoke a function template with different template arguments. Which one should be fixed at compilation. That seems to be his use case.

Comment: @sbi that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: A priori template templates are valid, you do *not* need to “provide parameters to the template to make it concrete.” However, perhaps this only works with class templates, not with function templates (I don’t know). With class templates, the syntax `template <template <typename T> class C>` would be correct, so OP’s attempt at least looks consistent.

Comment: @sbi, @There: I see. So it's much like simply having an templated function, but it is desired to have that held in Factor. Could you get the desired results by simply having a templated function? What is Factor meant to be used to do?

Comment: It sounds like you could accomplish what you want through constructor parameters to either your map or your policy. Have you explored that option? Or optionally, could you provide those values when you declare your map?

Comment: @JoshD could you please provide an example how I'm suppose to pass a args to a Policy ctor? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your `make_()` function template, it seems that what you actually want is `boost::lexical_cast<>()`. It does what your `make_()` does, only better. (For starters, your conversion doesn't check for errors at all.)